# Переменные в smarty

Tags: php, переменные, smarty

Где находятся переменные в SMARTY? Вот например в pay.tpl есть такое:

```
{$currency_sign}
```

как мне пробраться к этой переменной и изменить её значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы присвоить в самом шаблоне есть [`assign`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl). В Smarty3 можно писать так:

```
{$currency_sign = 'Новое значение'}
```

Если же вас интересует, где оно в PHP задается, попробуйте поискать по проекту `'currency_sign'`

Comment: @Johny, в Filezilla попробывал поиск по файлам с названием "currency_sign", ну то есть если это слово содержится в названии файла, то пусть покажет этот файл. Но ничего не нашло. Это вручную чтоли тысячи файлов надо перебирать и искать там currency_sign? :(

Comment: @ModaL попробуйте найти модуль, который подгружает шаблон pay.tpl,  а там в редакторе уже задать поиск самой переменной $currency_sign

Comment: Как это сделать? Ничего толкового нет - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1383484641-clip-5kb.png

Comment: не факт, что переменная присутствует в шаблоне. Может быть она вообще из БД берется.

Comment: @ModaL, что же это у вас за IDE такая, что не позволяет поиск по проекту делать?

Я смотрю вы не первый год в веб-разработке. Подберите себе толковый инструмент. Я рекомендую [PHPStorm][1]. ИМХО это единственный продукт, написанный на Java, который НОРМАЛЬНО работает :)

З.Ы. Это не реклама, а личное мнение


  [1]: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: "...в Filezilla попробывал поиск по файлам с названием "currency_sign", ну то есть если это слово содержится в названии файла, то пусть покажет этот файл..."
Слово должно содержаться в содержимом файла, а не в названии...
Или у Вас тут просто описка?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, скорее всего, эта переменная передана из PHP-файла.

Ищите подобное (быть может, тоже назван, pay.php):

```
$smarty->assign('currency_sign', значение);
```

Второй вариант, переменная задана в самом шаблоне:

```
{assign var="currency_sign" value="value"}
```